# C# - change adjacent button colour when clicked

Tags: c#

OK let's say we have buttons arranged in the following form 5x5

```
[11] [12] [13] [14] [15]
[21] [22] [23] [24] [25]
[31] [32] [33] [34] [35]
[41] [42] [43] [44] [45]
[51] [52] [53] [54] [55]
```

And want for example, if I click on button 34, to change the color of the button 24, 44, 33 and 35.
The problem is I do not know how to do that when I click on a button to return any of these values.
Take a pseudocode of what I want to do.

```
When I press the button [i, j]:
Change color of button[i-1, j];
Change color of button[i +1, j];
Change color of button[i, j +1];
Change color of button[i, j-1];
```

So when I press a button, I need to somehow get the values ​​i, j of the button and I may handle other buttons on the same style (i +1, j, etc.)

I could treat separately each button.....

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ // change colors
}
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ // change colors
}
 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ // change colors
}
....
 private void button25_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ // change colors
}
```

, .....but I have 25 buttons and I don't want to write the same code in all 25 keys.

What I want is that :

```
 private void button[i][j]_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
 button[i+1][j].BackColor = Color.Red;
 button[i][j+1].BackColor ...... etc. etc.  
  // I know is incorrect, but is just how I want to act, if you understand me.
}
```

Excuse my bad English.

Comment: Use arrays and add the same event handler to every button.

Comment: it might help you get more answers if you place additional tags that specify more the type of development your doing, i.e. winforms or asp.net webforms...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most elegant solution is to use `TableLayoutPanel` to arrange all the buttons. Then you can handle all the buttons this way:

```
        private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button clickedBtn = sender as Button;
            var cp = tableLayoutPanel1.GetCellPosition(clickedBtn);

            Button up = (Button)tableLayoutPanel1.GetControlFromPosition(cp.Column, cp.Row - 1);
            //up.Color = ...
            Button down = (Button)tableLayoutPanel1.GetControlFromPosition(cp.Column, cp.Row + 1);
            //etc
        }
```

Dont' forget to check if column/row is not null before subtracting 1

Comment: Brilliant. I'm sure it will work this way. Can not wait to try it! Thank you!

Comment: @user2105306 don't wait, try it ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could set the Tag property to the numbers then in the common click method you can something like:

```
int i = Math.Floor(((int)sender.Tag) / 10);
int j = ((int)sender.Tag) - i;
```

Or you could use arrays.

Comment: It might work. I will try tomorrow to rewrite my code a bit and come back to tell you if I succeeded. Thank you.